# Cakephp before page render disply an error for large content

Tags: cakephp

When I assign a large content to cake php .ctp file. While displaying the page. I got the following error.

The request timed out before the page could be retrieved.

How to handle such cases in cakephp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much data are you passing to the view? Or is it just a large view file with static text?

Answer (score 0):

increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini file (or in the script if it's allowed). Could you provide more information what does it mean "large content".